# with Preorder to traverse IntTree

Tags: haskell, preorder

I am trying to create a preorder Function to traverse a IntTree.

The Tree class is as following

```
data IntTree = Empty | Branch IntTree Int IntTree deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I have two questions
1. I get errors as shown below.

```
E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_2_a.hs:7:14: error:
    * Expected kind `* -> Constraint', but `IntTree' has kind `*'
    * In the type signature: preorder :: (IntTree c) => c -> [a]
  |
7 | preorder :: (IntTree c) => c->[a]

  |              ^^^^^^^^^
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

I don't see why. They occured at this following line

```
preorder :: (IntTree c) => c->[a]
```

2. I think that the following line is not right. I think I need to write other expressions instead of " l : preorder a : preorder r:[] "

```
preorder Branch a l r = l : preorder a : preorder r:[]
```

I thank you for the help in advance!!

```
main :: IO ()    -- This says that main is an IO action.
main = return () -- This tells main to do nothing

data IntTree = Empty | Branch IntTree Int IntTree deriving (Show, Eq)


preorder :: (IntTree c) => c->[a]
preorder Empty = []
preorder Branch Empty x Empty = [x]
preorder Branch a l r = l : preorder a : preorder r:[]
```

Answer (score 2):

For question 1: the signature

```
preorder :: (IntTree c) => c->[a]
```

is wrong: `IntTree` is not a typeclass, it is a plain type, so we can use it as it is.

```
preorder :: IntTree -> [Int]
```

The final type must be `Int`, since we are producing a list of integers, and not a  list of `[a]` for any `a`.

For question 2:
`:` prepends an *element* to a *list*, it has type

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Hence, it does not concatenate two lists. For that, use instead

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

as in

```
preorder (Branch a l r) = l : preorder a ++ preorder r
```

(There is no need to use `++ []` at the end)

Comment: Aw darn you added a question 1 section.  I liked our univocal double-answer.

Comment: @luqui I realized there was a question 1 after I answered question 2, so I first marked the answer as Q2-only and I started to edit to complete the answer. Yes, the "split" answers looked better, in some aesthetic way :)

Comment: Just now I have corrected it after your tipps. But there is still one error  in the following line:  `preorder Empty = []`. The error is ```E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_2_a.hs:8:1: error:
    Equations for `preorder' have different numbers of arguments
      E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_2_a.hs:8:1-19
      E:\Haskell\Uebungsblatt_2_Aufgabe_2_a.hs:9:1-35
  |
8 | preorder Empty = []

  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
[Finished in 0.5s]``` @chi @luqui

Comment: @LeonhardFelix You need more parentheses: `preorder Branch a l r = ...` is a function which takes 4 arguments, while what you want is `preorder (Branch a l r) = ...`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @chi   Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

For question 1:

```
preorder :: (IntTree c) => c->[a]
```

You are confusing classes and data types.  `IntTree` was declared with `data`, so it is not a typeclass but a regular data type, such as `Bool` or `Int`.  It is used the same way:

```
preorder :: IntTree -> [a]
```

The second thing is that you are not returning a list of any type `a` (lowercase letters are type *variables*), you are returning specifically a list of `Int`s, because that's what the tree contains.  So you must say so:

```
preorder :: IntTree -> [Int]
```